# excel file read answer not in proper format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

```
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('arrays.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
a = [[0.222333333333333, 0.048150492835172518, 'a12', 'a13', 'a11']]
print('writedata=',a)

row = 1
for col, data in enumerate(a):
    worksheet.write_row(row, col, data)

workbook.close()
x = pd.read_excel('arrays.xlsx')
print('readdata=',x)
```

Answer

```
writedata= [[0.222333333333333, 0.04815049283517252, 'a12', 'a13', 'a11']]                
readdata= Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0.222333333333333, 0.04815049283517252, a12, a13, a11]
Index: []
```

But how do I the get the simple answer of readdata like:

```
[[0.222333333333333, 0.04815049283517252, 'a12', 'a13', 'a11']]
```

which not include that words Empty data frame

please help me

Comment: Please update your question by improving the formatting of the code. Python is sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_excel` usually considers the first non-null row as the header. You can specify other wise by passing `None` to it.

To get the output you need, you will have to apply some changes:

```
x = pd.read_excel('arrays.xlsx', header=None)
x = x.dropna().as_matrix()
```

Output:

```
array([[0.222333333333333, 0.04815049283517252, 'a12', 'a13', 'a11']],
      dtype=object)

x.tolist()
[[0.222333333333333, 0.04815049283517252, 'a12', 'a13', 'a11']]
```